# how to improve opencart extension rating

Tags: php, opencart

I've uploaded the extension on official opencart extension directory. Now I want to improve the rating of my extension. Any suggestions that how can I do this. Any helpful answer will be appreciated.Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Provide proper documentation & demo of your extension.
- Respond ASAP when anyone asks for your plugin support.

Thanks